# ReactJS/Javascript/Graphql/React-apollo: Cannot read property 'loading' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, graphql-js

I am calling displayElements from the render function and getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'loading' of undefined`.  Why is this error showing up? The reason I think this error is showing up is because here will be no results upon initial rendering.  But when the submit button is click a query to the DB gets executed and I would like to display the results using the displayElements.

```
displayElements(){
        var data = this.props.getObjectsQuery;
        console.log(this.props);
        if(data.loading){
          return <option disabled>Loading...</option>;
        }else{
          return data.action.map(action => {
            return(<option key={action.action} value={action.timestamp}>{action.filename}</option>);

          })
        }
      }
```

Submit Button

```
handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log(this.state);
        this.setState({
          startTime: new Date(document.getElementById("startTime").value).valueOf(),//getElementById is a jQuery method
          endTime: new Date(document.getElementById("endTime").value).valueOf()
        }, () => {
          this.props.data.refetch({//Assign the inputvalues, which is the current state, to the variables after pressing the submit button
            startTime: this.state.startTime,
            endTime:this.state.endTime
          });
          console.log(this.state.startTime);
          console.log(this.state.endTime);
        });
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the conditon as `if(data)` and then write your code.

```
  displayElements(){
    var data = this.props.getObjectsQuery;
    console.log(this.props);
    if(data) {
      if(data.loading){
        return <option disabled>Loading...</option>;
      }else{
        return data.action.map(action => {
          return(<option key={action.action} value={action.timestamp}>{action.filename}</option>);
        })
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Now its saying this:`TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined`

Comment: how are you passing `getObjectsQuery` to this component ??

Comment: import getObjectsQuery from '../Queries';

Comment: then don't use props to access `getObjectsQuery `. `console.log(getObjectsQuery)` and check what it is logging

Comment: Upon initial loading this error shows up: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined`.

Comment: put `console.log(getObjectsQuery)` in the starting of `displayElements()`, you will still get an error, but I need to see what there in `getObjectsQuery`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178282/discussion-between-mcrist-and-n6dyn).